# Translation of Accelerators into Chinese

Tags: mfc, translation, chinese-locale

When translating an app (MFC in this case) into Chinese, what do I do with Accelerators? 
Is F1 still used for Help?
What about things like CTRL-A?  Will the translator know what to do those?
Any advice or links appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Chinese):

> Chinese keyboards are usually in US layout with/without Chinese input
>   method labels printed on keys.

They also have F-Keys, so <kbd>F1</kbd> for help is fine.

Don't translate accelerators, keep them in latin alphabet. Ampersand accelerators within text are usually moved to the right of the text, changed to uppercase and wrapped in parenthesis. For example "E&nter the text:" becomes "输入文字(&N):". There is no whitespace between Chinese text and the first parenthesis.

This is how the Windows "run" dialog looks in Chinese (simplified):

[image: Windows Run Dialog (zh-CN)]

And this is Notepad's menu:

[image: Notepad (zh-CN)]

You can see for yourself by installing a Chinese language pack and changing the primary display language to Chinese via the Windows settings app.